# Get change amount with listener and DoubleProperty

Tags: java, properties, java-8, listener

Given a listener added to a DoubleProperty, is there anyway to pass the amount the DoubleProperty changed to the listener like you can do with an Observable list?

```
someDoubleProperty.addListener(e -> {
 // System.out.println(e.change());
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming by `DoubleProperty` you mean `javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty`.

Rather than using an `InvalidationListener` use a [`javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html). A `ChangeListener` is a functional interface with this method:

```
void changed​(ObservableValue<? extends T> observable, T oldValue, T newValue)
```

which gives you the old value and the new value along with the `ObservableValue` that is the source of the change.

Since a `DoubleProperty` is an `ObservableValue` (which extends `Observable`) it has an overloaded method for adding a `ChangeListener`: `addListener(ChangeListener<? super T>)`. Note, however, that a `DoubleProperty` is an `ObservableValue<Number>` which means the type of the `oldValue` and `newValue` will be `Number`.

---

As pointed out by @Zephyr in the comments, I missed the fact you are also looking for the difference between the two values. While this is straightforward now that you have access to the old and new values (as you mention in the comments) I'll put an example here for completeness/so I fully answer the question.

```
someDoubleProperty.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    double diff = newValue.doubleValue() - oldValue.doubleValue();
    // Do something with "diff"...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear and well explained answer. Just what I needed.

Comment: I think the OP was also asking how to get the difference of the change.

Comment: You were right @Zephyr but with access to oldValue/newValue is enough to get me there :)

Comment: @Zephyr Looks like you were right :p I'll add it to my answer for posterity.